# adview at bottom of the screen

Tags: android, adview

I want to get my adView at bottom of the screen but nothing works for me. How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXX"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/webView"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

>

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this config on your `AdView`:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this configuration on the XML file that places the adView bellow the WebView and change the size of the WebView to what you want[![This is what it looks like now][1]][1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXX"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/webView">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz6Bg.png
```